# How would a moon that was stroking a planet with a tail appear to people on the planet?

Tags: moons, worldbuilding-resources, visuals

In my world, the moon has heard the poetry and romantic words of a person on the planet, and so has decided to flirt with and stroke said poet with their moon scale tail.

[image]

Their tail has magic, and so isn't gonna destroy the world, but I am not sure what it would look like from the perspective of someone on the planet seeing an 100 kilometer wide tail snake out from the moon and stroke someone.

An ideal answer would suggest either tools that can simulate what this would look like or useful artwork resources to generate what this would look like.

The dimensions of the moon are similar to our planet's earth and moon, as is the distance and material, although magic prevents mass extinction from the tail rubbing.

Comment: 100 km _wide_ tail?  Even with magic, that's like a mountain reaching down to "stroke" someone.  There'd be a lot of fatalities from heart attacks, if nothing else.

Comment: > How would a moon that was stroking a planet with a tail appear to people on the planet? Terrifying. A 100km wide ANYTHING coming down from the sky would cause chaos and probably spark WWiii.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94120)

Comment: I don't understand what your tail is, even though it looks like animal-ish rather than the tail of a comet. Problem is, when we will know what your tail is, the best answer would be "it will look like what you described". There's not therefore not really a better answer than restating your premises. This is a common issue when you are asking us for ideas, rather than working with a problem you're currently facing

Comment: Also, note that what people would feel like in front of this falls quite a bit into the story territory. I doubt that the arrival of giant, unknown element from space to an unknown society are not what psychology/sociology/history can teach us much about. Well... Beyond the classic "fall in awe" or "huddled up in terror" you see in most  alien invasion movies. A reaction you have to choose as a storyteller :).

Comment: While I would say this is an actual answer, I'd say it could use some stronger fundations to the statement. Have there been events in history where people met suddenly unknown giant things (ideally in the sky)? I don't know, planes, elephants, tanks... The bigger and higher it is, the better.

Comment: I am more interested in what a giant object in the sky looks like. I don't know what resources people have access to- maybe someone has a simulation program that lets you simulate it. Maybe there's an artwork series for 100km wide ships in the sky. The material is meant to be moon material, if that helps. I don't know what a 100km wide object in the sky coming for a person looks like, because that's never happened for me.

Comment: Relevant XKCD, Earth-Moon Fire Pole: https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/   You have to consider how the Moon and Earth are moving relative to each other.

Comment: @NepeneNep Any UFO in the sky will suffer from the same effects of any other known objects, be it mountains, skyscrapers or airplanes : Clouds obscuring the view, shadows getting blurrier the further they are from the object, [aerial perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_perspective) making things more blue... Nothing a quick look at pictures or any recent (and decent) alien/dogfighting movie with 3D effects cannot help with, even with moon rock ^^".

Comment: To help you, I found back some graphical references with massive objects : first, [the Arrival alien's spaceship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_(film)). Then, in the Halo game series there are huge [weather spires](https://www.halopedia.org/Weather_spire) (if you don't take the famous "[Halo Array](https://www.halopedia.org/File:HTV_JohnHalo_Concept_4.png)" ring you often see there). Starcraft 2 strategy game has [kilometers long ships in one of its cutscenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVbeoSPqRs4&t=27s). I wouldn't be surprised to find some big ships in Warhammer 40K, too ^^.

Comment: @Kilisi It's always hazardous to induce one's actions ; I mainly -if not only- downvote non-answering posts and intention-hurting frame-challenges. On the other end, I hint ideas to improve posts which receives negative criticism when I can. If lending my intuition hurt your feelings, I'll try to remember not to do that anymore with you. No promise though, I have the memory of a goldfish o_x .

Comment: Not much point in doing more. This question was closed for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Perspectives

Let's start with an analogue to paint a picture what you would see.

For this exercise we are on a flat Earth <sup>citation needed</sup>. Put a kilometres long and wide sheet on the ground, right next to a watchtower. Now put a string on the sheet, moving towards the non-existent horizon. If you stand on the watchtower on a clear day, you'll see the string moving away from you, but at a certain moment you'll not be able to see the string in the distance. It is too small. Now we can do two things. Change the size of the tower and the width of the string. A thicker string will be more visible. Changing the size of the tower is more tricky, as a higher vantage point can make it easier to see in certain conditions, but for now lets assume that a higher tower means more distance to the string, making it more difficult to see.

The string on the sheet is an analogue for the tail, the tower for your distance from the tail to it's ground point. Now we have this analogue, we need to understand more how the tail will look. Is it more like a tiny string, an electrical cable or one of those huge cables that can hold bridges aloft. The thickness will determine much from where the tail is visible and how far.

### What is visible on the moon

The moon is very roughly 400.000km away from us. It is moving closer and further away during it's travels around the Earth, but for our viewing pleasure it is mostly constant. The 'super moon' phenomena aren't fully understood, but it mostly only looks bigger. What can we see on the moon with the naked eye? Craters. One crater on the 'bottom' is of particular interest for this question, which is the Tycho crater. This crater is visible to the naked eye and has a diameter of 85km, smaller than the suggested tail. If the crater is visible, the tail should be big enough to see from beginning to end. It'll look like a small string, though like my reference to the super moon it can *look* incredibly big still, as we understand that it's big.

We can then imagine seeing the tail at a distance like we see mountains. Sure they look small if we look at a picture, but seeing them ourselves we know they are big. The best reference for size is mount fuji, which from the right angle has a width of 50km. The tail would come down twice the width of mount fuji, moving like a string upwards into the air. It'll keep going all the way to the moon, where it can neatly attach to the Tycho crater. To our analogue, we can stand on any size watchtower and look at a cable the likes you've never seen, moving further and further away and not becoming smaller for such an unimaginable distance it is hard to grasp.

### Not quite the end

As the header suggests, this analogue isn't quite true. We have to consider two more factors. Night and day. During the day the moon is most of the time not visible. We'll skip over the exceptions. During the day your string of mountain will likely disappear from a certain distance into space, as the light of the atmosphere is brighter than what the string part in space reflect to you. The same reason you don't see the moon during the day. At night the opposite can be true, where parts of the tail in the atmosphere is invisible thanks to too little light. Of course, if there's only a partial moon visible or no moon visible at night, this will also hide or show parts of the tail.

### Conclusion

During the day you'll see the tail moving into the air, disappearing as its brightness diminishes compared to the atmosphere. At night the opposite is true, where the bottom is not or barely visible, or can be traced by the absence of stars. But towards the moon the tail becomes visible, showing a shiny ribbon moving towards to moon.

This assumes good weather and good phases of the moon. It doesn't touch on the more difficult to predict viewings during twillight, different seasons, on the poles or similar. It also ignores the speed it would go over the landscape, assuming the tail moves in space in such a way to keep it in one place to caress the poet. It does give a good handle on the most common situations what people will write about, though with some inventiveness you could make some grand sights of the tail in special conditions.

Comment: The Earth's Moon is typically fairly visible in the daytime sky. It's bgb and bright enough to be visible during the daytime when it's up, even in the crescent phase.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to imagine what such a thing would look like, just consider that, for an observer on Earth at sea level, the horizon is located at about 5 km distance.

So, from one end to the other our sight can span 10 km.

If we get higher, we can see more, according to the relationship $d [km]\approx3.57\sqrt{h[m]}$.

You can see that something 100 km wide would cover the entire visible horizon for any observer lower than 200 meters above sea level.

In itself that is already an impressive sight. Refraction and atmospheric absorption would make the edges of the tail vague and undefined, and depending on the color of the tail could even make the tail not distinguishable from the sky in certain situations.